# Task usually does not run

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am newbie to parallel programming. I write the basic code below but it doesnt run always as I excepted.

```
Console.WriteLine ("Start");

Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine (i);
}

});

Console.WriteLine ("End");
```

I usually could not get the result of the loop 8-9 out of 10 trials. Sometimes it prints the loop results, sometimes not. But I it always prints the `Start` and `End`. Whats happening at the behind side ? Why sometimes I could not get the result of loop from time to time ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is terminating before the parallel loop gets a chance to print any output.

```
Console.WriteLine ("Start");
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine (i);
}
});

Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("End");
```

Pause by waiting for input, and you'll see the loop run correctly.

Comment: Using `Console.ReadLine()` might make sense in a test application, but in actual code, you should actually wait for the `Task` to finish. And in this case that's very easy: `task.Wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a readline at the end. You will see the following:

```
Start
End
0
1
2
3
4

Console.WriteLine("Start");

Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

});

Console.WriteLine("End");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must tell your main thread to wait till your task is over.

Your "End" was being printed in most cases before the task thread executed. Use `TaskContinuationOptions` to tell the parent thread to wait for its tasks threads to complete.

```
Console.WriteLine ("Start");
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine (i);
}
});
task.ContinueWith(ant =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted| TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
task.Wait();
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that the whole application ends before the `Task` runs. But your code won't help in that case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, I added a wait to the end.